# Is 'define()' in PHP secure?

Tags: php

I was told by another programmer `define` is secure for storing passwords and is harder to hack than a session in PHP.

I was reading the PHP manual, but can't seem to find anything about if `define` puts it's elements in the global space, can have all define elements listed (like print_r($_SESSION)), or if it is even secure somewhat at all.

PHP had one warning about unpredictable behavior, but I couldn't find much more than that.

```
define("CONSTANT", "Hello world.");
echo CONSTANT; // outputs "Hello world."

While it is possible to define resource constants, it is not recommended and may cause unpredictable behavior.
```

Basically my question is: Is `define` a really bad idea for passwords?

Comment: *"A constant is an identifier (name) for a simple value. As the name suggests, that value **cannot change** during the execution of the script..."* as per http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.php *"Is 'define()' in PHP secure?"* Yes, so that part is safe. Just don't go storing passwords in sessions.

Comment: Think about it. You have 10 users today, and tomorrow you have 20 users. What good is a defined password? Think databases

Comment: *"Is define a really bad idea for passwords?"* - that would depend and this question is starting to look "too broad" / "opinion-based", IMHO.

Comment: Also, **Why would you put a password in a session**. All you need in a session is a flag that says "They completed Login" and then maybe a `id` of the user row and maybe a name so you dont need to go back to the database for some of the stuff you use all the time in the system

Comment: Is define() viewable in any way like you can do with print_r($_SESSION) or other globals?  I guess that is what I was worried about most.

Answer (score 2):

This is what `get_defined_contants` will do:

> Returns the names and values of all the constants currently defined. This includes those created by extensions as well as those created with the define() function.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-defined-constants.php

Define is definitely not designed with security in mind. What you'd want to look for is something involving encryption.

Like others, I'm curious about why you'd want to store a password in the session or as a constant at all. Some details about what the password is for might help. I can't picture that you'd want to store it as part of users logging in to your app. Is it for your code to authenticate with an API?